# Shopvac drywall attachment too restrictive?

Tags: drywall

**I have :**

5HP 16Gal. Shopvac
 A drywall vacuum attachment , to suck up the dust while sanding.
 a brand new filter ( made for fine particles like dust)

**The Problem :**

When I start the vacuum, it seems okay.. but quickly slows down and starts to smell like it's overheating.

Should I not be using this powerful of a shop vac?  I attempted to adjust the holes on the attachment, but to no avail (no instructions are given).
  I'm thinking perhaps I need to open up the back port (exhaust port) .. would that help?

[image]

Comment: Your shopvac has an option to close the exhaust port? Where does the exhaust go when it's running with that port closed?

Comment: Link or picture (preferred) for the "drywall sanding attachment" ?

Comment: Your vac is Underpowered not overpowered.

Comment: @ojait I highly HIGHLY doubt that.. because my littler shopvac handles this attachment perfectly fine.

Comment: @BMitch there is a back covering .. it looks like I can open it and let exhaust out quicker than normal.  I'd have to take a pic to explain.  I'm not very knowledgeable obviously of shop vacs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Shop-Vac is more than a few months old and you are noticing a decrease in performance the smartest action you can take is to start looking for a replacement. That smell you detect after the motor has been running for awhile is its' death knell. When the motor heats up the winding insulation softens and melts. That's what you smelt.     Shop-Vac brand vacuums have become a disposable item. You can coax a few more weeks of life from it by putting less strain on the motor.  Opening the port on the sander head will lessen the strain on the motor, but at the cost of less suction. Some other suggestions are to install a "fine particulate" bag. This captures the fine drywall dust before it reaches the filter. Also regularly tap the filter to remove dust build-up. The pleated filters do the best job of keeping dust in the tank (they are the easiest to clean, too). The cap on the exhaust port is a baffle that deadens the noise from the motor and a diffuser that spreads exhaust air to soften it's flow. Removing it will increase performance slightly, but increase decibels and air flow.

Comment: I've updated the original question with the proper size, after googling around I realize I listed an incorrect size/power

Comment: also, I've already installed the fine particulate bag.. brand new

Comment: I knew your first post of 2 hp was way to small. 16 gallon is fine . I use the same sander with my Craftsman 6.0 hp.

Comment: do you know why I'm overheating then?

Comment: It's the manufacturer trying to increase their bottom line and profit margin. Shop-Vac has taken a steady nose dive in just the past few years.  The motor is the first thing to go or the power switch. If I had to offer a reason why the motor overheats I would guess the windings are of a to small gauge wire and the insulation (varnish) is to thin. All it takes is the windings shorting to each other and the motors dead. BTW any replacement motor you find will cost almost as much as a new vacuum. I'm giving Sears a chance, but don't see them being that much better.

Comment: You should also use the proper sanding sheet for maximum performance. There are 100 and 120 grit drywall 1/3rd size sheets made explicitly for vacuum sanders. They are crosshatched to vacuum dust easily and they can also be rinsed with water.

Comment: I went with the water-bong and my other smaller vac(working like a charm so far) , thanks for answering my questions.  I was afraid it was the motor just becoming disposable .  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I find the models that use filters plug up quickly. A contractor friend showed me what he had made using a 5 gallon bucket and plumbing fixtures. one pipe goes in and a 90 at the bottom of the bucket capped off then drill a bunch of 1/4" holes in the short pipe at the bottom. fill the bucket 1/2 way with water the suction pipe is short only 1" from the top the dust comes in and when bubbling up through the water the dust is trapped in the water, when you notice dust rinse and put fresh water in the bucket works great and no filters to buy. I have had mine for a few years. If cleaned at the end of the day it is not hard to clean if you forget it is a lot more work to clean out.

Comment: just like a bong.

Comment: Water trap filters for dry wall sanding work great. I've had a bucket of this sort for 15 years. It is a comercial product as opposed to home made.

Comment: @MichaelKaras incidentally I'd already ordered a water filtration system while .. but wanted to see if maybe I was just doing something wrong.

Comment: my bong vac attachment showed up last night.. couldn't wait to try it and it's working great with my smaller shop vac!

Answer (score 2):

Use a dry cyclonic pre-filter system such as the [Dust Deputy](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002JP315K).  Attach this to the lid of a 5-gal bucket using the kit.  No fussing or filling the bong-vac system.  It works great, I have used mine with all kinds of dusty stuff.

Comment: I've already ordered the water kit.. but if that doesn't fit the bill I'll look into your suggestion, thank you